# Why Term Rewriting?

Tags: term-rewriting

I've done a bit of googleing and have come up a bit short.

I am wondering what are the main reasons for computing scientists, programmers,
to study term rewriting, and/or term graph rewriting.

As far as I can tell, it just helps for basic reasoning about functional programs and (imperative) program control. Apparently, it is a topic of great interest to logicians and those who study constructive abstract algebras.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure that this will bring you more than you already know. But
then, I may fail to understand the reasons that make you wonder about
term rewriting. It does help.

As you may know, grammars are string rewriting systems. At the top of
the Chomsky hierarchy, you have type 0 grammars, which define
recursively enumerable (RE) anguages, and have the computational power
of Turing machines.

So that tells you that rewriting systems in general have a lot do do
with expressing algorithms.

The problem with strings in general is that there is no obvious way to
attach semantics to them.  It is a kind of amorphous rewriting.

What people are usually interested in is expressing algorithms in
specific domains that have structure and properties. Such domains are
often defined from elementary (atomic) entities, and closed by
various operations, possibly quotiented by equivalence relations, and
so on. These are often called algebras.

These domains are often abstract. But computations on their elements
can be expressed only on concrete representations. Terms are natural
represntation of these elements since they express how elements can be
obtained for other elements by application of operations, recursively
downto atomic elements (though general properties need not always go
all the way down). Terms are a kind of tree structure syntax that can
be manipulated to express algorithms (as for string). But the operator
operand structure of terms also allows associating to them semantics
in some abstract domain by means of homomorphisms.

Rather than take the very formal view of wikipedia and many texts on
this topic, just consider programs. It is usually recognized that a
convenient syntactic representation of programs is what is called
Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).  But an AST is just a term to represent a
program object.  Denotational semantics is a way of defining abstract
domains and associate values from these domains to AST (or AST
subtrees) by mean of homomorphisms. Programs in AST form can be
transformed or optimized by applying rewriting rules (I am not
asserting that all optimizations can or should be done that way).

Transformation of algebraic expressions for various purposes can be
expressed by term rewriting. For example, the simplification of some
expressions. Various types of computations can also be naturally
expressed as term rewriting, such as the computation of
derivatives. Term rewriting is also used sometimes to define canonical
forms in algebras, when the same semantic entity can have several
syntactic representations.

I do suggest that you look at the [wikipedia article on this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting).

Answer (score 7):

My thought is, it's because Term Rewriting is something extremely fundamental, and that lets you describe things in an extremely low-level way, independent of any hardware.

Term-rewriting can describe grammars, but it also gives you the mechanics to described logical systems, like first order logic, etc. Proving and deductions can be written as term-writings. Then, the substitution of term-rewriting is really the only operation you have. The simplicity here is valuable because you're describing logic, so you can't use the full complexity of logic to describe your system (since that's the system you're trying to describe).

This then gives you the mechanics you need to talk about the lambda calculus as a logical/axiomatic system, which gives you an extremely formal, fundamental version of computation.

Turing Machines are useful, but their underlying definitions require you to have a concept of sets, functions, etc. There's a lot more math that's assumed to have been build.

Lambda calculus, on the other hand, is defined in terms of logic, so you can use it without much in the way of definitions for set theory, functions, etc.

Term rewriting, modeled by logic, isn't only applicable to functional programing. When you're doing formal verification of hardware or software, you're always going to do reasoning of some sort, and this reasoning can be modeled by term rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

One very practical reason is that it leads to the construction of [program transformation systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), tools that let one manipulate the code for programs as terms (abstract syntax trees) using surface-syntax rewrites.

One example of this my system, the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), which has been used for a wide variety of program analysis and massive transformation tasks.  You can see how DMS [expresses rewrites](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html).  These rewrites are applied by an associative-commutative term rewriting system that operates behind the scenes.